# Allowing letters in my routes Yii 2

Tags: yii, yii2

Currently I have something like this in my routes

```
'c/<id:\d+>' => 'c/view',
```

I want to use both integers & letters in my "id" however, this doesn't work. What would I need to replace in  to make that work?

Comment: Try with: 'c/<id:[a-zA-Z0-9]+>' => 'c/view

Answer (score 1):

In the route `'c/<id:\d+>' => 'c/view'` you have `\d+` which is a regular expression where d+ matches the numbers.  If you change it to `<id:([a-zA-Z0-9])+>` it will allow you to user either words, letters or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
'c/<id:[[:alnum:]]+>' => 'c/view'
```

[:alnum:] is a POSIX bracket expression, which I like to use to keep my urlRules terse. I also find them easy to remember.

You can also use:

- `[:alpha:]` - equivalent to [A-Za-z]
- `[:digit:]` - equivalent to [0-9]
- `[:lower:]` - equivalent to [a-z]

More here:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html